# awslinux /etc/cron.daily doesn't execute logrotate file

Tags: linux, cron, logrotate

sorry about low level english

### IN MY STAGING SERVER

I want logrotate every day(nginx)

so I create logrotate file in `/etc/logrotate.d/`

**/etc/logrotate.d/nginx**

```
/var/log/nginx/*log {
    create 0644 nginx nginx
    daily
    rotate 30
    missingok
    notifempty
    nocompress
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y%m%d
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        if [ -f /var/run/nginx.pid ]; then
                 kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
        fi
    endscript
}
```

and I insert logrotate file in `cron.daily`

**/etc/cron.daily/logrotate**

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with 
[$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

and I check `/etc/anacrontab`

**/etc/anacrontab**

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1       5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7       25      cron.weekly             nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45     cron.monthly            nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

and I check `ls -la  /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily`

**/var/spool/anacron/cron.daily**

```
20180221
```

nginx logs will rotate like `access.log, access.log-20180222`

but when i command `run-parts /etc/cron.daily`

It doesn't working...

strangly when i insert command line `/usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf`

it work very well!

I think `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` not executed when `run-parts /etc/cron.daily`

but In my local docker
I command `run-parts /etc/cron.daily`, It works

only staging server is not working ,,

why `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` file not working when I command `run-parts /etc/cron.daily`??

Answer (score 1):

problem solved

it is permission problem

`chmod 700 logrotate`

`-rw------- logrotate` -> `-rwxr--r-- logrotate`

it works well